# How to use pdflib TET command-line tool

Tags: text, extract, pdflib

I just downloaded pdflib TET and can't figure out how to use the command line tool. I installed the .msi file but when I go to command line tet command is not recognized. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Andrija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to go to the "bin" directory of your TET package and then you can call "tet.exe".

In addition, you can also use the full qualified path name to the "tet.exe".

or you add the bin directory to your PATH, or place the "tet.exe" to a directory within your path. then you can use "tet.exe" from all directories.

Comment: Thank you! It appears that it can't be run just by clicking on tet.exe (forgive me if this is a noob thing to expect :))